# How do you do new lines in .jade files?

Tags: html, pug

How do you do new lines in .jade files? Something which would effectively correlate to 
 in html. I saw that you can put things on new lines using the list (ul : li) commands but it seems to break when you assign a blank line to a li: command.

What I'd like is the submit button to appear a couple blank lines down from the 'uPass' input box:

```
block content
            form(method='post',action='/login')
                input(name="uName" type="text" placeholder="User Name")
                input(name="uPass" type="password" placeholder="Password")
                input(type="submit" value="Login")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct answer is: use CSS to add a space between the elements.

Anyway, here's how you add a `<br>` in Jade (it's THAT simple)

```
block content
    form(method='post',action='/login')
        input(name="uName" type="text" placeholder="User Name")
        input(name="uPass" type="password" placeholder="Password")
        br
        br
        input(type="submit" value="Login")
```

Or even

```
input(name="uPass" type="password" placeholder="Password")
| <br><br>
input(type="submit" value="Login")
```

Comment: I understand that CSS adds the space, I was looking for the syntax of the jade counterpart to breakline.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `|` to do a new line, so:

```
ul
  li
    | Some text in your li
    | Some more text
```

Or use the `.`

```
ul
  li.
    Ya some li text!
    More!
```

Comment: I'm looking to do this with objects like input boxes and buttons, please see the original question for an example.

Comment: I hadn't, br is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this mixin:

```
mixin newline()
  | #{'\n'}
```

Then call it:

```
b text
+newline
b more text
```

The results:

```
<b>text</b>
<b>more text</b>
```